# Cypress terminal error: Property does not exist on type 'cy & CyEventEmitter

Tags: angular, typescript, cypress

**Tech stack:** Angular v15 and Cypress V12

My component and e2e tests seem to run fine but I get these weird terminal errors when running the tests.

It could be an issue with my Cypress configuration for my shared commands.

**This is my shared commands:**

```
declare global {
  namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable {
      loginAs(role?: string): Chainable<any>,
      isWelcomePage(): Chainable<any>,
      openMenu(): Chainable<any>,
    }
  }
}

Cypress.Commands.add('loginAs', (role?: string) => {
  const user = Cypress.env('user');
  cy.visit(Cypress.env('local'));
  cy.get('#mat-input-0', { timeout: 30000 }).should('be.visible').type(user.email);
  cy.get('#mat-input-1', { timeout: 30000 }).should('be.visible').type(user.password);
  cy.get('.btn').click({ force: true });
});
```

**This is my cypress configuration:**

```
import { defineConfig } from "cypress";
const { verifyDownloadTasks } = require('cy-verify-downloads');

export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('task', verifyDownloadTasks)
    },
    specPattern: "cypress/e2e/**/*.cy.ts",
  },
  chromeWebSecurity: false,
  screenshotsFolder: "cypress/snapshots",
  trashAssetsBeforeRuns: true,
  viewportWidth: 1400,
  viewportHeight: 1200,
  video: false,
  defaultCommandTimeout: 10000,
  env: {
    local: "http://localhost:4200/",
    staging: "hidden",
    backend: "hidden",
    user: {
      email: "hidden",
      password: "hidden",
    },
  },
  component: {
    devServer: {
      framework: "angular",
      bundler: "webpack",
    },
    specPattern: "**/*.cy.ts",
  },
});
```

**This is the terminal errors:**

[image]

**Exact error messages**

- Property 'loginAs' does not exist on type 'cy & CyEventEmitter'.

**Current Attempt:**

**Tsconfig:**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": false,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "es2020",
    "allowJs": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2020",
      "dom"
    ],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "types": ["cypress", "cy-verify-downloads"],
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": false,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": false,
    "strictTemplates": false
  },
  "include": [
    "./src",
    "./cypress/support/index.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

**index.d.ts file:**

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />
export { }

declare global {
  namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable {
      loginAs(role?: string): Chainable<any>,
      isWelcomePage(): Chainable<any>,
      openMenu(): Chainable<any>,
    }
  }
}
```

I got the same terminal errors when I run the component tests.

[image]

Comment: My current guess is that I'm not doing the namespace Cypress interface Chainable correctly? if so please provide an example of how to do this correctly

Answer (score 5):

There's probably a few ways to tackle it, here's one

- put the custom command types in `cypress/support/index.d.ts`
- add a reference to base cypress types
- make the `.d.ts` a module with a dummy export

```js
/// <reference types="cypress" />
export {}

declare global {
  namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable {
      loginAs(role?: string): Chainable<any>,
      isWelcomePage(): Chainable<any>,
      openMenu(): Chainable<any>,
    }
  }
}
```

In `tsconfig.json` add your `index.d.ts`

```js
{
  ...
  "include": [ "./src/app", "./cypress/support/index.d.ts"],
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I've updated my code above to show current attempt.
The example you gave didnt work. Can you check above to see if I've missed anything

Comment: If seems like I needed to add 
/// <reference types=“cypress” /> to top of each component test as well as the index.d.tschanges above. I still get the errors though.

Comment: It seems to only complain for e2e tests and not component tests in the terminal. However, those errors only show when I select component testing in the gui and not e2e weirdly.

Comment: It does actually work, but maybe your tsconfig is a little out of whack. I'll review your adjustments a bit later.

Comment: Don't forget you are dealing with typescript - restart Cypress to see the effects of any changes.

Answer (score 0):

I once got the same issue, and just realized that the type defined is actually correct, but the placement is not.

In my case, I use NextJS to add custom or modifiable types, usually Cypress will create a `support/commands.ts` folder, then just input the custom type that you want to define.

[image]

and add your cypress func